# разделение шаблона класса на заголовочный файл и файл реализации

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как разбить на разные файлы объявление шаблона класса и его реализацию?

Имеется шаблон класса:

```
template<typename keyT>
class Tree
{
...
};
```

В заголовочный файл пишу следующее:

```
template<typename keyT>
class Tree
{
    struct Node;
public:
    ~Tree();
    void add_element(keyT element);
    ....................
};
```

В файл реализации(.cpp) вот это:

```
#include "tree_implementation.h"
class Tree
{
    struct Node
    {
        ...
    };
public:
    ~Tree()
    {
        ...
    }
    void add_element(keyT element)
    {
        ...
    }
    .......
};
```

Но такой код отказывается компилироваться. Компилятор выдает ошибку о том, что шаблон класса уже переопределен. Как правильно разделить этот шаблон класса на заголовочный файл и файл реализации?

Comment: В .cpp он у вас вообще не шаблонный.